# Python/SQLAlchemy - How to quickly query database with multiple WHERE clauses?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, list, sqlalchemy

First post ever for me.

What I am trying to do is connect to a Microsoft SQL Server Database and query a table for results such that any of the selected columns' values exist in the same list. Here's the connection code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, MetaData, Table

connect_string = 'mssql+pyodbc://user:password@server/database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0'
engine = create_engine(connect_string)
connection = engine.connect()

metadata = MetaData(bind=None)
table = Table('FwdPackage', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

I connect to the table fine and have successfully queried from it, but the queries take way longer than they do in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I ran the below code for 30 minutes until cancelling it and proceeding to look for answers online. I can't find much so I figure I have a misunderstanding somewhere.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_

s = select([table.c.ColumnOne, table.c.ColumnTwo, table.c.ColumnThree, table.c.ColumnFour]).where(
    or_(
        table.c.ColumnOne.in_((barcodes)),
        table.c.ColumnTwo.in_((barcodes)),
        table.c.ColumnThree.in_((barcodes)),
        table.c.ColumnFour.in_((barcodes))
    )
)

result = connection.execute(s).fetchall()
```

Where `barcodes` is a list created from a pandas Series, like so: `barcodes = df['Barcode'].tolist()`.

I imagine the problem is `barcodes` specifically, but the `.where` to me is the broad problem.

Any help here will be greatly appreciated! I would love to make this as fast as possible.

**EDIT**

SQLAlchemy generates this select statement, returned by `print(s)`:

```
SELECT "FwdPackage"."EVSBarcodeBase", "FwdPackage"."PrimaryBarcode", "FwdPackage"."TrackingNum", "FwdPackage"."EVSBarcode" 
FROM "FwdPackage" 
WHERE "FwdPackage"."EVSBarcodeBase" IN (:EVSBarcodeBase_1, :EVSBarcodeBase_2, :EVSBarcodeBase_3, :EVSBarcodeBase_4, :EVSBarcodeBase_5, :EVSBarcodeBase_6, :EVSBarcodeBase_7, :EVSBarcodeBase_8, :EVSBarcodeBase_9, :EVSBarcodeBase_10, :EVSBarcodeBase_11, :EVSBarcodeBase_12, :EVSBarcodeBase_13, :EVSBarcodeBase_14, :EVSBarcodeBase_15, :EVSBarcodeBase_16, :EVSBarcodeBase_17, :EVSBarcodeBase_18, :EVSBarcodeBase_19, :EVSBarcodeBase_20, :EVSBarcodeBase_21, :EVSBarcodeBase_22, :EVSBarcodeBase_23, :EVSBarcodeBase_24, :EVSBarcodeBase_25, :EVSBarcodeBase_26, :EVSBarcodeBase_27, :EVSBarcodeBase_28, :EVSBarcodeBase_29, :EVSBarcodeBase_30, :EVSBarcodeBase_31, :EVSBarcodeBase_32, :EVSBarcodeBase_33, :EVSBarcodeBase_34, :EVSBarcodeBase_35, :EVSBarcodeBase_36, :EVSBarcodeBase_37, :EVSBarcodeBase_38, :EVSBarcodeBase_39, :EVSBarcodeBase_40, :EVSBarcodeBase_41, :EVSBarcodeBase_42, :EVSBarcodeBase_43, :EVSBarcodeBase_44, :EVSBarcodeBase_45, :EVSBarcodeBase_46, :EVSBarcodeBase_47, :EVSBarcodeBase_48, :EVSBarcodeBase_49, :EVSBarcodeBase_50, :EVSBarcodeBase_51, :EVSBarcodeBase_52, :EVSBarcodeBase_53, :EVSBarcodeBase_54, :EVSBarcodeBase_55, :EVSBarcodeBase_56, :EVSBarcodeBase_57, :EVSBarcodeBase_58, :EVSBarcodeBase_59, :EVSBarcodeBase_60) OR "FwdPackage"."PrimaryBarcode" IN (:PrimaryBarcode_1, :PrimaryBarcode_2, :PrimaryBarcode_3, :PrimaryBarcode_4, :PrimaryBarcode_5, :PrimaryBarcode_6, :PrimaryBarcode_7, :PrimaryBarcode_8, :PrimaryBarcode_9, :PrimaryBarcode_10, :PrimaryBarcode_11, :PrimaryBarcode_12, :PrimaryBarcode_13, :PrimaryBarcode_14, :PrimaryBarcode_15, :PrimaryBarcode_16, :PrimaryBarcode_17, :PrimaryBarcode_18, :PrimaryBarcode_19, :PrimaryBarcode_20, :PrimaryBarcode_21, :PrimaryBarcode_22, :PrimaryBarcode_23, :PrimaryBarcode_24, :PrimaryBarcode_25, :PrimaryBarcode_26, :PrimaryBarcode_27, :PrimaryBarcode_28, :PrimaryBarcode_29, :PrimaryBarcode_30, :PrimaryBarcode_31, :PrimaryBarcode_32, :PrimaryBarcode_33, :PrimaryBarcode_34, :PrimaryBarcode_35, :PrimaryBarcode_36, :PrimaryBarcode_37, :PrimaryBarcode_38, :PrimaryBarcode_39, :PrimaryBarcode_40, :PrimaryBarcode_41, :PrimaryBarcode_42, :PrimaryBarcode_43, :PrimaryBarcode_44, :PrimaryBarcode_45, :PrimaryBarcode_46, :PrimaryBarcode_47, :PrimaryBarcode_48, :PrimaryBarcode_49, :PrimaryBarcode_50, :PrimaryBarcode_51, :PrimaryBarcode_52, :PrimaryBarcode_53, :PrimaryBarcode_54, :PrimaryBarcode_55, :PrimaryBarcode_56, :PrimaryBarcode_57, :PrimaryBarcode_58, :PrimaryBarcode_59, :PrimaryBarcode_60) OR "FwdPackage"."TrackingNum" IN (:TrackingNum_1, :TrackingNum_2, :TrackingNum_3, :TrackingNum_4, :TrackingNum_5, :TrackingNum_6, :TrackingNum_7, :TrackingNum_8, :TrackingNum_9, :TrackingNum_10, :TrackingNum_11, :TrackingNum_12, :TrackingNum_13, :TrackingNum_14, :TrackingNum_15, :TrackingNum_16, :TrackingNum_17, :TrackingNum_18, :TrackingNum_19, :TrackingNum_20, :TrackingNum_21, :TrackingNum_22, :TrackingNum_23, :TrackingNum_24, :TrackingNum_25, :TrackingNum_26, :TrackingNum_27, :TrackingNum_28, :TrackingNum_29, :TrackingNum_30, :TrackingNum_31, :TrackingNum_32, :TrackingNum_33, :TrackingNum_34, :TrackingNum_35, :TrackingNum_36, :TrackingNum_37, :TrackingNum_38, :TrackingNum_39, :TrackingNum_40, :TrackingNum_41, :TrackingNum_42, :TrackingNum_43, :TrackingNum_44, :TrackingNum_45, :TrackingNum_46, :TrackingNum_47, :TrackingNum_48, :TrackingNum_49, :TrackingNum_50, :TrackingNum_51, :TrackingNum_52, :TrackingNum_53, :TrackingNum_54, :TrackingNum_55, :TrackingNum_56, :TrackingNum_57, :TrackingNum_58, :TrackingNum_59, :TrackingNum_60) OR "FwdPackage"."EVSBarcode" IN (:EVSBarcode_1, :EVSBarcode_2, :EVSBarcode_3, :EVSBarcode_4, :EVSBarcode_5, :EVSBarcode_6, :EVSBarcode_7, :EVSBarcode_8, :EVSBarcode_9, :EVSBarcode_10, :EVSBarcode_11, :EVSBarcode_12, :EVSBarcode_13, :EVSBarcode_14, :EVSBarcode_15, :EVSBarcode_16, :EVSBarcode_17, :EVSBarcode_18, :EVSBarcode_19, :EVSBarcode_20, :EVSBarcode_21, :EVSBarcode_22, :EVSBarcode_23, :EVSBarcode_24, :EVSBarcode_25, :EVSBarcode_26, :EVSBarcode_27, :EVSBarcode_28, :EVSBarcode_29, :EVSBarcode_30, :EVSBarcode_31, :EVSBarcode_32, :EVSBarcode_33, :EVSBarcode_34, :EVSBarcode_35, :EVSBarcode_36, :EVSBarcode_37, :EVSBarcode_38, :EVSBarcode_39, :EVSBarcode_40, :EVSBarcode_41, :EVSBarcode_42, :EVSBarcode_43, :EVSBarcode_44, :EVSBarcode_45, :EVSBarcode_46, :EVSBarcode_47, :EVSBarcode_48, :EVSBarcode_49, :EVSBarcode_50, :EVSBarcode_51, :EVSBarcode_52, :EVSBarcode_53, :EVSBarcode_54, :EVSBarcode_55, :EVSBarcode_56, :EVSBarcode_57, :EVSBarcode_58, :EVSBarcode_59, :EVSBarcode_60)
```

Table schema, indexes:

```
[{'name': 'FwdPackageKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': True,
  'dialect_options': {'mssql_identity_start': 1,
   'mssql_identity_increment': 1}},
 {'name': 'FwdInboundShipmentKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'FwdShipmentKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'FwdContainerKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PostalManifestKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'CreateDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'CreateTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'MerchantOrgKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ContainerStatusKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PrimaryBarcode',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'EVSBarcode',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'EVSBarcodeBase',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'TrackingNum',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PackageOrderID',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'AddlRef1Num',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'AddlRef2Num',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PackageIdentifier',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InboundTrailerNum',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InboundBillOfLading',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PostalManifestNum',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'CustManifestNum',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'CAPSStatementNum',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=20, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'OutboundBillOfLading',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InductionReceiptNum',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'OriginFacilityKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InductionFacilityKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ShipToFacilityKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'USPSEntryFacilityKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PostalPkgAttributeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ClientPkgAttributeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InboundShipOpenDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InboundShipOpenTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InboundShipProcessedDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InboundShipProcessedTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InductionScanDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InductionScanTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ManifestDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ManifestTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'OutboundShipDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'OutboundShipTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ShipmentDelivDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ShipmentDelivTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'USPSEntryDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'USPSEntryTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'DeliveryDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'DeliveryTimeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'RevenueRecogDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ServiceTypeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'MailClassKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'USPSRateCategoryKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PostalProcessCatKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'MailToAddressKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'MailToPostalCodeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'CostZoneKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'OrigPostalCodeKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'TotalPostageAmt',
  'type': MONEY(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'FacilitySurchargeAmt',
  'type': MONEY(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ActualWeight',
  'type': NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=4),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'Length',
  'type': NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=4),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'Width',
  'type': NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=4),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'Height',
  'type': NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=4),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'BillStatusKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'BillCycleDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'AuditKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'MatchAuditKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'SrcContainerID',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'SrcPackageID',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'SrcLabelID',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'InShipContainerID',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ParentContainerID',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'USPSManifestID',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'eVSFileHeaderRecordID',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'DelFlag',
  'type': CHAR(length=1, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'CreateDate',
  'type': DATETIME(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'UpdateDate',
  'type': DATETIME(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PostageBaseFeeAmt',
  'type': MONEY(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PostageDiscountAmt',
  'type': MONEY(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PostageSurchargeAmt',
  'type': MONEY(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'PostageSpecialServicesAmt',
  'type': MONEY(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'USPSPricingCategoryKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'USPSSortCategoryKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'SortKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ManifestFacilityKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'AltCarrierTrackingNum',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'OutboundOrigShipDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ShipFromFacilityKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'AuditServiceAmt',
  'type': MONEY(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ETAHubDelivDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ETAUSPSEntryDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ETADeliveryDateKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'EnclosurePostageAmt',
  'type': MONEY(),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'EnclosureWeight',
  'type': NUMERIC(precision=12, scale=4),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'EnclosureUSPSPricingCategoryKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'ClassOfServiceKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'CountryKey',
  'type': INTEGER(),
  'nullable': False,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False},
 {'name': 'OriginalPrimaryBarcode',
  'type': VARCHAR(length=50, collation='SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'),
  'nullable': True,
  'default': None,
  'autoincrement': False}]
```

```
[{'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_AddlRef1Num',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['AddlRef1Num',
   'CreateDateKey',
   'MerchantOrgKey',
   'PrimaryBarcode',
   'EVSBarcode',
   'EVSBarcodeBase',
   'TrackingNum',
   'PackageOrderID',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_CreateDate',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['CreateDateKey',
   'FwdShipmentKey',
   'FwdContainerKey',
   'PostalManifestKey',
   'InductionScanDateKey',
   'USPSEntryDateKey',
   'MerchantOrgKey',
   'USPSPricingCategoryKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_DelivDate',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['DeliveryDateKey',
   'SortKey',
   'SrcContainerID',
   'MerchantOrgKey',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'ShipToFacilityKey',
   'ServiceTypeKey',
   'MailToPostalCodeKey',
   'USPSPricingCategoryKey',
   'ShipFromFacilityKey',
   'CreateDateKey',
   'PostalManifestKey',
   'FwdContainerKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_IndScanDate',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['InductionScanDateKey',
   'USPSEntryDateKey',
   'PostalManifestKey',
   'CreateDate',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'InductionScanTimeKey',
   'MerchantOrgKey',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'ServiceTypeKey',
   'MailToPostalCodeKey',
   'FwdShipmentKey',
   'SortKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_ManifestDate',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['ManifestDateKey',
   'MerchantOrgKey',
   'EVSBarcode',
   'ActualWeight',
   'USPSPricingCategoryKey',
   'ShipFromFacilityKey',
   'FwdContainerKey',
   'SortKey',
   'FwdShipmentKey',
   'TotalPostageAmt',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'USPSEntryFacilityKey',
   'PostalManifestNum',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_MerchantOrg',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['MerchantOrgKey',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'USPSPricingCategoryKey',
   'ManifestFacilityKey',
   'InductionScanDateKey',
   'ActualWeight',
   'EVSBarcode',
   'ServiceTypeKey',
   'MailToPostalCodeKey',
   'PrimaryBarcode',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'ManifestDateKey',
   'OriginFacilityKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_OutboundShipDate',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['OutboundShipDateKey',
   'FwdShipmentKey',
   'FwdContainerKey',
   'ManifestDateKey',
   'OutboundShipTimeKey',
   'SortKey',
   'ShipFromFacilityKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_PostalManifestNum',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['PostalManifestNum',
   'FwdShipmentKey',
   'FwdContainerKey',
   'ContainerStatusKey',
   'EVSBarcode',
   'OutboundBillOfLading',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_ServiceType',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['ServiceTypeKey',
   'ShipToFacilityKey',
   'USPSEntryFacilityKey',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'ETADeliveryDateKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_Sort',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['SortKey',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'SrcContainerID',
   'ParentContainerID',
   'ShipmentDelivDateKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_USPSEntryFac',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['USPSEntryFacilityKey',
   'EVSBarcode',
   'ShipToFacilityKey',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'ShipFromFacilityKey',
   'ETADeliveryDateKey',
   'InductionScanDateKey',
   'ServiceTypeKey',
   'ETAUSPSEntryDateKey',
   'ManifestDateKey',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IDX_FWDPackage_PostalCode',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['MailToPostalCodeKey',
   'OrigPostalCodeKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_Audit',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['AuditKey',
   'FwdInboundShipmentKey',
   'PostalManifestKey',
   'FwdContainerKey',
   'FwdShipmentKey',
   'DelFlag',
   'BillStatusKey',
   'InShipContainerID',
   'CustManifestNum',
   'OriginFacilityKey',
   'InboundShipOpenDateKey',
   'InboundShipProcessedDateKey',
   'ParentContainerID',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'eVSFileHeaderRecordID',
   'CAPSStatementNum',
   'USPSEntryFacilityKey',
   'ManifestDateKey',
   'ManifestFacilityKey',
   'PackageOrderID',
   'ContainerStatusKey',
   'InductionScanDateKey',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_EVSBarcode',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['EVSBarcode', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_EVSBarcodeBase',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['EVSBarcodeBase', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_FwdCont',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['FwdContainerKey',
   'USPSPricingCategoryKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_FwdPackageKey',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['FwdPackageKey',
   'USPSEntryFacilityKey',
   'PostalManifestKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_FwdShip',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['FwdShipmentKey',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'CreateDateKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_InductionFac',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['InductionFacilityKey', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_MailClass',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['MailClassKey', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_ManifestFacility',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['ManifestFacilityKey', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_MatchAudit',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['MatchAuditKey',
   'FwdShipmentKey',
   'ContainerStatusKey',
   'InductionScanDateKey',
   'USPSEntryDateKey',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_PostManifest',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['PostalManifestKey',
   'USPSEntryFacilityKey',
   'OutboundShipDateKey',
   'OutboundShipTimeKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_PrimaryBarcode',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['PrimaryBarcode', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_SrcPackageID',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['SrcPackageID',
   'DelFlag',
   'InductionScanDateKey',
   'InductionScanTimeKey',
   'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_TrackingNum',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['TrackingNum', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_USPSPricingCategory',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['USPSPricingCategoryKey', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_USPSRateCat',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['USPSRateCategoryKey', 'FwdPackageKey']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_MerchantOrgKey_N',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['MerchantOrgKey',
   'FwdPackageKey',
   'PrimaryBarcode',
   'PackageIdentifier',
   'ClientPkgAttributeKey',
   'SrcPackageID']},
 {'name': 'IX_FwdPackage_BillStatusKey',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['BillStatusKey',
   'FwdPackageKey',
   'MerchantOrgKey',
   'MailClassKey',
   'CostZoneKey',
   'TotalPostageAmt',
   'ActualWeight',
   'SrcPackageID']},
 {'name': 'IDX_FwdPackage_InductionScanDateKey',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['InductionScanDateKey',
   'FwdPackageKey',
   'FwdContainerKey',
   'PrimaryBarcode',
   'DeliveryDateKey',
   'ServiceTypeKey',
   'ETADeliveryDateKey']},
 {'name': 'IDX_FwdPackage_DelFlag',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['DelFlag',
   'FwdPackageKey',
   'CreateDateKey',
   'MerchantOrgKey',
   'OriginFacilityKey',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'Length',
   'Width',
   'Height',
   'SrcPackageID']},
 {'name': 'IDX_FwdPackage_CreateDateKey',
  'unique': False,
  'column_names': ['CreateDateKey',
   'FwdPackageKey',
   'MerchantOrgKey',
   'AddlRef1Num',
   'AddlRef2Num',
   'OriginFacilityKey',
   'InductionFacilityKey',
   'USPSEntryFacilityKey',
   'ClientPkgAttributeKey',
   'InductionScanDateKey',
   'MailToPostalCodeKey',
   'OrigPostalCodeKey',
   'SrcPackageID',
   'CountryKey']}]
```

Total rows = 198,923,378 (maybe this is why haha)

Comment: If you want to make it as fast as possible, it might be worth checking `pymssql`. In my experience it is a **a lot** faster than `pyodbc`. Also, you don't need to import `pyodbc` in you example, unless you use it somewhere else now shown in the code.

Comment: @iuvbio I think I had that import from earlier when I tried it out. I took out the import and I will look into pymmsql. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @snakecharmerb (a) I don't know what this means. Do you mean the raw SQL query? (b) Okay I edited the post and added this. (c) schema and indexes added. (d) added.

Answer (score 2):

The point of interest here is not python, but the **SQL Query** which is generated. You could boost execution time up by cleverly setting indexes.

Therefore, open SQL Management Studio (SSMS), type in the SQL Statement, and before you start the query,  set the option **"Show ACTUAL Execution Plan."**.

SSMS will you give then hints which indexes you could set in order to speed up the query. It will also generate all the `CREATE INDEX` statements which you will need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I looked into doing this but I don't have privileges to 'Show Execution Plan', as I get a 'Permission Denied' response in SQL. Reached out to people at work and they can't give me that access. Only select few people get it. That being said I think this is the right path. Any way I could figure out which indexes to set a different way?

Comment: Hmm, under these circumstances; Would you have permission to create any indexes at all?

Comment: I'm not positive. I've never created any indexes before, but I could try with your help. This mini project depends on speeding up these queries so if I can't I will abandon it most likely.